# get Primary Key from SP

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert, primary-key

With SQL, when inserting values into a Table from a SP, is it possible to get the value of the Primary Key before the values are added to the Table?

Comment: "before the values are added to the Table"? No, because someone might get in before you and insert something. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @spender - You seem to be assuming `IDENTITY` it is certainly possible with externally generated PK values such as sequences or guids.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Depends what is the primary key. Are you inserting it, is the SP generating it or is it auto incremented within the table?

Comment: It is of course possible. Tell us what DBMS you are using and an example of your table structure and maybe someone could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible, leveraging the power of relational databases. Assuming, like Martin Smith said, that you *are* using an autogenerated key, then you can use a transaction to do what you're looking for.

Here's the general idea:

1. Start a transaction.
2. Do the insertion.
3. Use the primary key to do whatever you need to do, including updated the inserted row to reflect the value.
4. Commit or rollback

By beginning a transaction before your insert, you can assure that no one else will be able to see the new rows until you commit your transaction. If the key is not to your liking, you can rollback the transaction, and no one else will know. If the key is adequate, you can modify the rows you have just inserted before committing.

Since you have a transaction, no one else can see the intermediate data you have inserted before you commit. Thus, you can update the rows that you have just inserted as if you have the primary key before your actual insert.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server the best way to do this is with your MERGE or INSERT command use the OUTPUT clause to get your key back.  Even though this is not before the insert you can use the results of the OUTPUT to join back the results of your data to insert subsequent children records.

Also if you are using SQL server you can look at IDENT_CURRENT function which will return the current identity value of a table.  If you are writing your SQL in a set based fashion the OUTPUT that I mention above works best for me.